# turn by turn navigation with google maps sdk ios

Tags: ios

Is it possible to have turn by turn navigation in iOS app by using google maps SDK for iOS. I want achieve this without launch google map app/ URL schema. Is this possible inside the app.

Comment: No - no API for this and prohibited via their T&C

Comment: @Rajath did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Is it really prohibited from Apple?